# My drag-able popups also drag the visual element owning them. How can I fix this?

Tags: c#, wpf

**Update:** I have made a discovery, that if I always return out of OnMouseLeftButtonDown in the MapCanvas, I am able to use the popup the way I intend to. This suggests to me that the behavior of the MapCanvas is preventing the culprit. I may have an answer to my problem soon.

I'm worried that the ultimate problem causing this issue has eluded me, so I will document as much of my work as I can. I apologize for this being a long post, but I want to share what I have as clearly as I can. Immediately below is a summary of the problem I'm facing:

I have a popup contained by a map line, which in itself is contained in a map. When the user left-clicks and drags, it drags the map. I wrote a behavior to also click and drag the popup. When I left-click the popup and attempt to drag it, instead I drag the map - the popup remains stationary. When I let go of the left mouse button, the popup is then "stuck" to my cursor, and it drags everywhere I move my mouse.

Alright, now for the lengthy detailing:

I have written a custom mapping control for use within WPF applications. I can't share the whole definition, but some important bits looks like this:

```
public class MapCanvas : Canvas
{
    public override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(e);
        if (e.ClickCount >= 2)
        {
            //We zoom in a level
        }
        else
        {
            this.Focus(); //We get the keyboard
            if (this.CaptureMouse())
            {
                mouseCaptured = true;
                previousMouse = e.GetPosition(null);
            }
        }
    }

    public override void OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(e);
        this.ReleaseMouseCapture();
        mouseCaptured = false;
    }

    public override void OnMouseMove(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseMove(e);
        if (mouseCaptured)
        {
            //Translate the map tiles based on the current position of the mouse
        }
    }
}
```

I share the overrides because they are how I handle map interactions like dragging the map, double-click zoom, etc. I also think it plays a role in what's causing the problem.

I have also written a type called MapLine, which binds to a collection of geo-spatial coordinates, transforms them to screen points, and displays them on the map. These lines are added to a VisualCollection within my MapCanvas. I have trimmed their definition and laid it out below:

```
public abstract class MapLine : FrameworkElement
{
    private VisualCollection popupChildren;

    private VisualCollection regularChildren;
    protected override int VisualChildrenCount
    {
        get
        {
            return regularChildren.Count;
        }
    }

    protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index)
    {
        if (index < 0 || index >= VisualChildrenCount)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("index");
        else
        {
            return regularChildren[index];
        }
    }

    protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        HitTestResult result = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(this, Mouse.GetPosition(this));
        if (result != null && result.VisualHit is DrawingVisual)
        {
            //If we find the Visual in our collection of regular children, we launch a new popup
            if(ThisIsRegularChild((DrawingVisual)result.VisualHit))
            {
                Popup pointPopup = GeneratePopup();
                this.popupChildren.Add(pointPopup);
                pointPopup.IsOpen = true;
            }
        }

        base.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(e);
    }

    private static Popup GeneratePopup()
    {
        Popup popup = new Popup();
        Stream popupContentStream = currentAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream("ResourcePath.xaml");
        popup.Child = (UIElement)XamlReader.Load(popupContentStream);
        popup.StaysOpen = true;
        popup.Placement = PlacementMode.Mouse;
        popup.AllowsTransparency = true;

        Interaction.GetBehaviors(popup).Add(new PopupDragManager());

        return popup;
    }
}
```

Alright, so to summarize what I've shared about the MapLine: It also overrides OnMouseLeftButtonDown, and checks to see if the user clicked on a visual element owned by this MapLine; if we do, we launch a popup. That Popup has a System.Windows.Interactivity.Behavior attached to it - it seemed like the simplest way to address my needs to make the popop drag-able. Here is that Behavior's definition:

```
private class PopupDragManager : Behavior<Popup>
    {
        private bool mouseDown;
        private Point oldMousePosition;

        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            AssociatedObject.MouseLeftButtonUp += MouseLeftButtonUp;
            AssociatedObject.MouseLeftButtonDown += MouseLeftButtonDown;
            AssociatedObject.MouseMove += MouseMove;
        }

        private void MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            mouseDown = true;
            oldMousePosition = AssociatedObject.PointToScreen(e.GetPosition(AssociatedObject));
            AssociatedObject.Child.CaptureMouse();
        }

        private void MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!mouseDown) return;
            var newMousePosition = AssociatedObject.PointToScreen(e.GetPosition(AssociatedObject));
            var offset = newMousePosition - oldMousePosition;
            oldMousePosition = newMousePosition;
            AssociatedObject.HorizontalOffset += offset.X;
            AssociatedObject.VerticalOffset += offset.Y;
        }

        private void MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            mouseDown = false;
            AssociatedObject.Child.ReleaseMouseCapture();
        }
    }
```

Just like the MapCanvas, if we compress the left mouse button, move the mouse, and release the left mouse button, we want the popup to drag across the screen. Instead, when I attempt to left-click and drag, the MapCanvas gets dragged, like so:

Here, I am looking at a map; clicking on a blue point opens the popup.
[image]

I have just opened my pop, ready to drag it aside
[image]

You can see, minus the jitter from cropping, that my popup remains in place, and my map has been dragged instead
[image]

Not featured in my screenshots is the "sticky" behavior of the popup once I let go of the left mouse button: the popup will *begin* dragging at this point, and I can only escape it by double clicking.

If you have made it this far, I congratulate you. I can only hope that patience of that magnitude might coincide with an understanding of my problem, and you may be able to shed some light on this bug.

Answer (score 0):

Well... I learned something today. I was not aware that, in routed events (and perhaps other events as well), you can mark the event as handled by setting your EventArgs.Handled equal to true.

The following code solves all of my problems:

```
        private void MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            mouseDown = true;
            oldMousePosition = AssociatedObject.PointToScreen(e.GetPosition(AssociatedObject));
            AssociatedObject.Child.CaptureMouse();
            e.Handled = true;
        }
```

That simple new line of code prevents anybody else from getting the MouseLeftButtonDown event.